# uploadify flash button not working in browser without flash in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, uploadify

I have written a multiple upload with uploadify jquery, but when I check it on a system with no flash player installed a blank area is present in the region of the uploadify flash button.

How can I show the user a missing plug-in prompt, like in other sites, to ask them to install the latest flash player plug-in...

or suggest some option to make upload possible from a button click (single/multiple) even when the user doesn't have flash installed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checked whether browser got flash plug-in and if not then hide the uplodify div and shown a normal file upload div... that solves the problem...

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Ajax file upload](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) to upload files in non-flash case and use the ashx file by Uploadify to upload file, but multiple file upload will not be possible in IE...